# np.load() unusually slow for larger files

Tags: python, numpy

So I'm loading up some files using np.load() in the size range 150MB to 250MB. each file contains an array that has 5 sub arrays with some data. some files are loaded in under a second while others take up to 5 seconds to load and since I have a lot of these files they take quite a while to work with them all due ot the slow loading times. But, I have noticed that if I split the files into 5 smaller files (1 sub array per file) then the loading time is always easily under a second per 5 files.

what could be causing this? how can I speed up np.load() without splitting each file into smaller files?

Comment: How are you measuring the run time? Perhaps splitting the file allows it to fit in the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) which makes loading faster?

Comment: i just very roughly counted it, but loading all the files takes about a minute after splitting them up while before splitting them took close to 10 minutes. I doubt it is just the page cache.

Comment: What format are the files in and how do you call `np.load`?

Comment: (Just a guess - [`load`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.0/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L266-L432) delegates to [`read_array`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.0/numpy/lib/format.py#L595), which may end up in [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.0/numpy/lib/format.py#L653) branch.)

Comment: Sorry for not answering your question earlier, I think the format is just a the pickle file format, they are saved with `np.save(file)` and loaded with  `np.load(file)` , no additional parameters. @kazemakase

Comment: Is `file` a string with the file name or some other object?

Comment: when saving it is `with open('filename', 'wb')as file: np.save(file)` when loading it is simply `np.load('filename')` @kazemakase

Comment: That's not it then. Uh..wait.. you use sub-arrays, does that mean you have nested arrays?

Comment: yes `main_array = [arr1,arr2,arr3,arr4,arr5]`. saving and loading up main_array is way slower than saving and loading up arr1-5  individually. @kazemakase

Comment: `main_array` is a list, which `np.save` will turning to an array.  If `arr1` etc differ in size the resulting array will have shape (5,) and object dtype.  That's important information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The root of the problem is that there is not really a concept of sub-arrays in numpy.

Consider this example:

```
import numpy as np

a1 = np.ones(2**17)
a2 = np.arange(2**18)
a3 = np.random.randn(2**19)

a = np.array([a1, a2, a3])

print(a.dtype)  # object
```

If you put arrays into an array numpy does not know that they are arrays. Instead, it treats them as generic Python objects. This is what the [documentation of `np.save`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) has to say about that:

> **allow_pickle** *: bool, optional*
>
> Allow saving object arrays using Python pickles. [...] Default: True

So what happens is that the sub-arrays are processed by the pickler, which is super inefficient. Obviously, this does not happen when you save the arrays separately. Now they are stored efficiently as numpy arrays. Unfortunately, you cannot simply set `allow_pickle=False` because then it won't let you store object arrays.

The solution is to use [`np.savez`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html) to store multiple arrays. Here is a timing comparison with above's arrays:

```
np.save('test.npy', a)
%timeit np.load('test.npy')  # 10 loops, best of 3: 40.4 ms per loop

np.savez('test2.npz', a1, a2, a3)
%timeit np.load('test2.npz')  # 1000 loops, best of 3: 339 µs per loop
```

You can retrive the arrays with

```
 x = np.load('test2.npz')
 a1 = x['arr_0']
 a2 = x['arr_1']
 # ...
```

It may be nicer to pass the arrays as keyword arguments to `savez`, which allaws you to give them names:

```
np.savez('test3.npz', a1=a1, a2=a2, timmy=a3)
x = np.load('test3.npz')
a1 = x['a1']
a2 = x['a2']
a3 = x['timmy']
```

Comment: So, what if you were to save a multidimensional matrix for example a matrix of the shape (1024,1024,1024,1024) would this be impossible to do efficiently through numpy? (I probably could flatten it,save it and then load and slice it to the appropriate dimensions but is there a more elegant way to do it?)

Comment: A multidimensional array is no problem. You can simply save it with `np.save`. Note that `[arr1,arr2,arr3,arr4,arr5]` is **not** a multidimensional array - it is a list of arrays which can lead to performance problems as you observed